# Send commands to a remote machine application with Python

Tags: python, subprocess, remote-access, telnetlib

I want to do the following in Python.
Connect to a remote machine open an application there and then send some commands to this application.
My idea was to do it through telnetlib and subprocess.
I managed to connect to the machine and start the application (with telnetlib alone), but I am not sure how to continue.
Is it possible?

P.S. I am also open to ideas to do it another way, but I would prefer to do it with python.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use pexpect.

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('telnet 192.168.0.1')
child.expect('[Ll]ogin') #you use the expected output, here will match either Login or login
child.sendline('username')
child.expect('[Pp]assword')
child.sendline('password')
child.expect('your remote prompt')
child.sendline('command')
```

you can install pexpect using pip

You can also have a list of expect:

```
index = child.expect['[Ll]ogin', '[Pp]assword']
if index == 0:
    child.sendline('username')
else index == 1:
    child.sendline('password')
```

Comment: Nice idea, thank you!
I will try it out.
P.S. Yes, I was planning to use telnet.